# Grid events - send data to user when he clicks the grid

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to make a data binded grid template in Silverlight for WP7 and, when I click one of the grids that appear on the page, i want to send some data that was binded to that grid. Example:

in this image is presented such a grid (it is an app presented by scottgu on his blog):
http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/image_thumb_661DF74A.png

when the user click one of the grids here, i want to show him a message with the text in the grid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example from Scott Gu uses a ListBox

Typically to respond to the user touching the ListBox, then you would intercept the ListBox Selected Item Changed event - or you would put a Button or other touchable element within each ListBoxItem.

This question you ask really is quite a beginner question - no problem with that - but I suspect you might benefit from reading through one or more tutorials.

This tutorial takes you through some navigation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_windowsphonenavigationandcontrolslab_topic2

Here's a big list of resources, including lots of tutorials - http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/68196.aspx

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I'm a beginner when it comes to interfaces, that's true, and this is just a personal project. I thought about adding a button, but I hoped I can do it without one.